# Defining a constant

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble defining a constant.

Here is how I have it defined:

```
const float tableOffset = 200;
```

Here is how I try to use it (see very end):

```
[self.voteTbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - bottomBar.frame.size.height - tableOffset)];
```

However, this does not work and actually set the correct height.  This code DOES work:

```
[self.voteTbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - bottomBar.frame.size.height - 200)];
```

I've tried switching to int with no luck.  The compiler gives no warnings or errors.

Comment: I'm not sure which one did it but it worked.  Would you mind putting an answer explaining the 'f' and CGFloat?  Thanks!

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer, and if you'd like me to come up with a bit more detail explaining what is going on I can probably do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you try "200.0f" in your const declaration?

Also, just to be super precise, use "CGFloat" and not "float". In general, for the times I need to use floats (or CGFloats), I add a "f" character at the end of the numbers to signify to the compiler that yes, this really is a float.